# does not execute a file on os x with $PATH

Tags: path, executable

I have dowloaded blat [from here](http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/admin/exe/macOSX.x86_64/blat/). I have also added in to executable path:

```
PATH=$PATH:/Users/katja/Desktop/MyDocuments/Programms/blat
```

But I can run the program only from the folder where it is situated and only by typing `./blat` and not simple `blat`, therefore homer does not find it. What should I do in order to be able to run a program just `blat`?

`which blat` gave nothing.

```
echo $PATH
/Users/katja/Desktop/MyDocuments/Programms/blat
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add to your `PATH` the directory in which the executable is located, without the executable name:

```
PATH=$PATH:/Users/katja/Desktop/MyDocuments/Programms
```